# PHP stdClass Object with array inside

Tags: php, arrays, clio-api

I have this array.  I have tried a few things but not getting what I want.
I tried a foreach loop but it does not seem to do it easly and the process takes a long time.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [display_number] => 100140
                    [client] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => TAUQIR SHEIKH ET AL
                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [display_number] => 100141
                    [client] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => YOLANDA SHEIKH ET AL
                        )

                )
```

I want it to be one simple array

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100140
            [1] => TAUQIR SHEIKH ET AL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100141
            [1] => YOLANDA SHEIKH ET AL
        )
```

Ok So the old code works but now they updated the API and this made it worse.  The response is now

```
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [display_number] => 100140
                                    [client] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => TAUQIR SHEIKH ET AL
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [display_number] => 100141
                                    [client] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => YOLANDA SHEIKH ET AL
                                        )

                                )
```

I tried this with the new code... But the array is empty.  Where am I going wrong?

```
//clean and make into an array
        $matter_array = array();     
        if(!empty($response_Decode->data->data) && 
         is_array($response_Decode->data->data)) {
            foreach ($response_Decode->data->data as $info) {
                $d = array();
                $d[] = $info->display_number;
                $d[] = $info->client->name;
                $matter_array[] = $d;
            }
        }

        print_r($matter_array);  //For testing
        die(); //For testing
```

Comment: Why don't you use array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I just simplified the array... AND THAT WORKS!

```
//clean and make into an array
        $response_Decode=$response_Decode->data;
        $response_Decode=$response_Decode[0];
        //print_r ($response_Decode);
        //die(); //For testing
        $matter_array = array();     
        if(!empty($response_Decode->data) && is_array($response_Decode->data)) {
            foreach ($response_Decode->data as $info) {
                $d = array();
                $d[] = $info->display_number;
                $d[] = $info->client->name;
                $matter_array[] = $d;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend asking who/what process is populating your dataset first and possibly adjust it there.

If not available then looping is required.

```
$results = array();     
if(!empty($object->data) && is_array($object->data)) {
    foreach ($object->data as $info) {
        $d = array();
        $d[] = $info->display_number;

        if(!empty($object->client)) {
            $d[] = $object->client->name;
        }

        $results[] = $d;
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

I'm paranoid with empty(). Code not tested but should get you on the right track.

Comment: I wish they would give it to me clean.  Thier API is really bad.  CLIO. 
They really don't want you to use PHP but that is what I know best.

That got me close.  The name is missing.  
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100140
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100141
        )

Comment: Here is what the code looks like

 //clean and make into an array
  $matter_array = array();     
  if(!empty($resp->data) && is_array($resp->data)) {
   foreach ($resp->data as $info) {
    $d = array();
    $d[] = $info->display_number;

    if(!empty($resp->client)) {
     $d[] = $resp->client->name;
    }

    $matter_array[] = $d;
   }
  }

  print_r($matter_array);

Answer (score 0):

SO you were close... Thank you.

```
//clean and make into an array
    $matter_array = array();     
    if(!empty($resp->data) && is_array($resp->data)) {
        foreach ($resp->data as $info) {
            $d = array();
            $d[] = $info->display_number;
            $d[] = $info->client->name;
            $matter_array[] = $d;
        }
    }

    print_r($matter_array)
```